# How to Set Stack Pointer in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, assembly

I'm currently trying to implement Coroutine in C++ on Windows by using a heap allocated side-stack.
But after some googling, I only found [this implementation](http://mfichman.blogspot.ca/2011/05/lua-style-coroutines-in-c.html) which relies on `<uContext.h>`.

As it seems like uContext.h is deprecated from the POSIX standard, I doubt there would be support on Windows.

Is there a way to change the stack pointer on Windows from either C or C++ code?
Assembly is fine too (Intel).

Thanks,

Comment: Write assembly code, assign the ESP value.  Or just don't bother, co-routines are already supported in the winapi.  Use [a fiber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.  Certainly less fun, the only good reason you'd use co-routines on modern multi-core processsors.

Comment: [setcontext(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setcontext.2.html) does much more than changing the user-side stack and frame pointer registers. it changes the kernel perception of the stack!

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Changing stacks is more than updating the stack pointer. If other bookkeeping is not maintained, the operating system assumes the process has been compromised by malware and terminates the process. Use fibers.